# PHP - loadHTMLFile() no me carga el documento html

Tags: php, dom

Estoy intentando modificar el código de una pagina html tras rellenar un formulario con los nuevos datos que se tienen que mostrar. Al salvar el formulario me dirijo a un archivo php para guardar los cambios en la base de datos y desde ahí acceder al archivo .html para modificarlo:

```
<?php

// Guardar cambios en base de datos OK

//Modificar html
$error="";
$file = "cIndex.html"; // el fichero se encuentra en la misma ruta 
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
if( file_exists("cIndex.html") == true )
   $DOM->loadHTMLFile($file);   //entra aqui, fichero encontrado
else
   $error = "No existe";  

$DOM->loadHTMLFile($file);

$cName = $DOM->getElementsById('cName'); //al añadir esta línea me da error 500 Internal Server Error. Si la quito $DOM lo devuelve vacío.

$DOM->saveHTML(); 

$respuesta = array (
    "error" => $error, //""
    "file" => $file, // "cIndex.html"
    "DOM" => $DOM  //lo devuelve vacío {}
);
echo json_encode($respuesta);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La llamada a [DOMDocument::saveHTML()](http://php.net/domdocument.savehtml) devuelve una cadena con el contenido del HTML generado por el DOM.

La forma correcta de usarlo sería:

```
<?php
// Guardar cambios en base de datos OK
//Modificar html
$error = "";
$file = "cIndex.html"; // el fichero se encuentra en la misma ruta 
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
if( file_exists($file) == true ) {
   $DOM->loadHTMLFile($file);   //entra aqui, fichero encontrado
} else {
   $error = "No existe";  
}

$DOM->loadHTMLFile($file);

/* Aquí puedes hacer lo que quieras con el DOM */
$cName = $DOM->getElementById('cName');

$html = $DOM->saveHTML(); 

$respuesta = array (
    "error" => $error, //""
    "file" => $file, // "cIndex.html"
    "DOM" => $html  //lo devuelve vacío {}
);
echo json_encode($respuesta);
```

He cambiado `DOMDocument::getElementsById()` por [`DOMDocument::getElementById()`](http://php.net/domdocument.getelementbyid).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! $html me devuelve el contenido de la pagina aunque con un formato diferente: "DOM":"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\"><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"><meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\"><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"><meta [...]

Comment: Perdon, quería añadir algo mas al comentario: después de $DOM->loadHTMLFile($file); intento acceder a un elemento: $cName = $DOM->getElementsById('cName'); pero me da error 500 Internal Server Error. No puedo modificar el contenido del html.

Comment: En el log de error del servidor te estará saliendo el error real, ¿podrías mostarlo?

Comment: Ahh, ya veo el error, te sobra una "s". Edito mi respuesta.

Comment: Recuerda que sólo debería haber un único elemento con un `id`, por eso esa llamada está en singular.

Comment: Mil gracias! Todo el tiempo he pensado que el error venía de loadHTMLFile.. una pregunta más, para guardar los cambios en el propio fichero html debería usar $DOM->saveHTMLFile("cIndex.html")

Comment: Sí, así es :) Recuerda votar positivamente las respuestas que veas útiles (hasta que no tengas más reputación creo que no podrás hacerlo) y marcar la respuesta correcta para dar por cerrada la pregunta.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, funciona perfectamente!